# create theme on shopify using api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to create an app and within the app the user can install a theme, however, I can't seem to work out why the theme is not being created. It keeps pulling the themes already installed on my store to the console, my code doesn't seem to create a theme that would show up on my shopify store.

server.js

```
    router.post('/api/theme', async (ctx) => {

    try {

      const results = await fetch("https://" + ctx.cookies.get('shopOrigin') + "/admin/themes.json", {
        headers: {
          'X-Shopify-Access-Token': ctx.cookies.get('accessToken')
        },

      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log("https://" + ctx.cookies.get('shopOrigin') + "/admin/api/2020-01/themes.json", json);
        });


      ctx.body = { 
          data: results
      };


    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  });
```

frontend .js file

```
 async function getUser() {
        var url = `/api/theme`;
        var method = 'post';
        const theme = {
            theme: {
                name: "Lemongrass",
                src: "https://codeload.github.com/Shopify/skeleton-theme/zip/master"
                }
        };
      const data = JSON.stringify(theme);
      fetch(url, { method: method, body: data})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a theme you need a zip archive of the theme you like to create.

The end point should be `/admin/api/2020-01/themes.json` and the body should be something like this:

```
{
  "theme": {
    "name": "Theme name",
    "src": "http://themes.shopify.com/theme.zip",
    "role": "unpublished"
  }
}
```

Please refer to https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/theme#create-2020-01 for more information.

At the moment from your code I don't see neither the correct POST request, neither the archive file.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I have updated my question with the code I have on my frontend file. When I run the code it prints out the themes.json file on my console, however, i can't seem to get it so my theme gets added to themes.json.